# Crontab failing to run a python script (runs fine manually)

Tags: python, ubuntu, cron

I am in the learning phase of ubuntu server. I have a python script that texts me the weather each morning, that script works perfectly when I run it from the command line. However when I try to set up a crontab entry, it does not work. The following line is what I put into my crontab file:

```
30 11 * * * cd /home/ubuntu/documents && /usr/bin/python /home/ubuntu/documents/weatherText.py
```

I also tried the following:

```
30 11 * * * /usr/bin/python /home/ubuntu/documents/weatherText.py
```

When I type either of the following commands into the terminal, my python script works great.

```
1.) cd /home/ubuntu/documents && /usr/bin/python /home/ubuntu/documents/weatherText.py
2.) /usr/bin/python /home/ubuntu/documents/weatherText.py
```

It has to be a problem with cron, right? Thanks for your time if you are viewing this now.

Edit: Here is the system log cron entries:
[image]

Comment: Did you check cron's logfiles?

Comment: @MattSchuchard I added them to my post!

Answer (score 0):

To know what is the problem exactly, write your commands in a .sh

In you case:

**myscript.sh**

```
#!/bin/bash
set -x
cd /home/ubuntu/documents
/usr/bin/python /home/ubuntu/documents/weatherText.py
```

With `set -x` all commands are printed in console.

and then execute your script with cron:

```
30 11 * * * /fullpathscript/myscript.sh > /anypath/cronlog.log 2>&1
```

where `/anypath/cronlog.log` will be created automatically.
this log show you what is the exactly error of your logic of script.